# riscv GCC Compiler didn't find the library

Tags: riscv

I have installed riscv compiler using homebrew. I need to connect the ioctl library, but the compiler for some reason does not find the header file, while I run the program on a regular compiler, no errors occur.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIzBv.png)

My os: MacOs Catalina